# synthesis of dynamic mux on std_logic_vector bytes

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

I have a FIFO who's size is determined according to a parameter in the package:

`signal fifo : std_logic_vector(FIFO_SIZE*8 -1 downto 0);`

I also have a 4 bit vector (numOfBytes) saying how many bytes are in the FIFO at any given time (up to 8).
I want the data out (a single byte) from the FIFO to be determined according the numOfBytes signal:
`Do <= fifo(to_integer(unsigned(numOfBytes)*8 -1 downto to_integer(unsigned(numOfBytes)*8 -8) when numOfBytes /= x"0" else (others => '0');`
when simulating, this works well, however when I try to synthesis it (using Synopsys DC) I get an elaboration error upon linking the design saying "Constant value required (ELAB-922)".

The ELAB code means "This error message occurs because an expression in the indicated line of your RTL description does not evaluate to a constant value, as required by the language."

How else can I make the output mux so it will undergo synthesis?
if not for the parameter i'd change the Do line to a regular mux, but it can't work with the parameters. (I can't call fifo(63 downto 54) when fifo is 4 byte...)

p.s. 
I tried working with conv_integer in the beginning, but changed to to_integer(unsigned())due to answers found on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal indexes used to construct a range have to be compile-time constants for synthesis to accept them.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1) Change your FIFO to use an array. This is the standard way of declaring any form of memory, such as a FIFO.

```
type fifo_type is array(0 to FIFO_SIZE-1) of std_logic_vector(8-1 downto 0);
signal fifo : fifo_type;
...
Do <= fifo(to_integer(unsigned(numOfBytes))-1) when(numOfBytes/=0) else (others=>'0');
```

2) Use a loop to convert the variable into a constant. This is a common way to code a generic mux.

```
Do <= (others=>'0');
for i in 0 to FIFO_SIZE-1 loop
    if(numOfBytes=i+1) then
        Do <= fifo((i+1)*8-1 downto i*8);
    end if;
end loop;
```

I would recommend the first approach for larger, memory-based FIFOs, and the second for smaller, register-based ones.

Comment: by the way, is this kind of problem a common problem? I see that I received two answers almost immediately and almost identical.

Comment: Zennehoy, the second answer solved it very nicely. and it almost didn't require me to change my design! now i have a netlist in hand :) I don't understand how come you didn't need to_integer(unsigned(numOfBytes)), how come the VHDL accept this kind of conversion?

Comment: @user2141046 That's the beauty of using `unsigned` rather than `std_logic_vector` whenever possible. As `unsigned` is known to represent a number, VHDL allows comparing it directly with `integer`.

Comment: @user2141046 Coding a FIFO or other form of memory is very common in VHDL. That you received two answers almost immediately is probably more a matter of good luck though.

Comment: @user2141046 Then you might be using `IEEE.std_logic_unsigned`, which tells VHDL to treat all `std_logic_vector` as `unsigned`. This is frowned upon though, since it is non-standard and error prone. Much better to use `unsigned` directly instead.

Comment: you learn something new everyday... thanks. I used (to_integer(unsigned(numOfBytes)) just in case (don't want to be frowned at :) )

Comment: Hi... this post is quite old... why your second solution converts a variable into a constant?

Comment: @Lukkio Sorry for the delay, I've been out of town. Admittedly the phrasing is a bit far-fetched. What's happening in the second solution is that you create hardware for all possible ranges in parallel (one range per iteration), and then add a multiplexer to select the range you are interested in based on the value of `numOfBytes`. Within the if statement, `i = numOfBytes-1`, so `i` is effectively `numOfBytes` converted to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If the FIFO created with a number of bytes, instead of combining it into the same `std_logic_vector` then Synopsys DC may be able to handle it.  Code could look like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture syn of mdl is

  ... Declaration of FIFO_SIZE natural constant

  type fifo_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal fifo : fifo_t(FIFO_SIZE - 1 downto 0);

begin

  ... Handling FIFO insert and remove

  Do <= fifo(to_integer(unsigned(numOfBytes))) when numOfBytes /= x"0" else (others => '0');

end architecture;
```

Comment: didn't try your solution because of Zennhoy's solution - I'm after source close and wanted to minimize the changes to my code. declaring the array and working accordingly would have been a major change I simply didn't want to do at the current design stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a runtime-dynamic size to the FIFO, use a `generic` on your entity.

If you truly need a dynamic sized FIFO, you'll have to use a loop in a process as someone else said.  But be very careful how you use such a FIFO, as if you change the size of it while someone is reading or writing, bad things may happen!